# what is the difference between building static and dynamic language for .net?

Tags: .net, clr, cil, dynamic-language-runtime

I am student and I want to build my own .net language for the general purpose, just to see how it is done, and to learn something new. What do you you think what is better choice? To build static language which targets CLR or to build dynamic language on top of DLR?

1. What steps in process of building these two kinds of languages are different?
2. What are the available tools for generating scanner, parser and CIL code? I found that people recommend antlr parser generator for generating AST, and then translating that to DLR expression tree, so you doesn't need to generate CIL code.

Comment: Everybody should build a new .NET language, just for fun.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I see problems, but none severe... The question in the title is a better question than the ones in the text. It's the most answerable.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely recommend ANTLR, and the book for it.  Unless you really know your grammar generation, you'll need the reference material.

I would also recommend using the ANTLR AST to generate CodeDom.  You could use the DLR or not, depending on what kind of a language you want to make.

I've had great success with both those routes though.

I've also generated CIL, which wasn't awesome but did work.  Leave that as a last resort.

Comment: You can generate CIL from CodeDom?

Comment: You can generate anything you want from CodeDom, you write both ends of it (the CodeProvider and CodeGenerator) and thusly have total control.  When I was generating IL though, it was via a non-CodeDom generator (this was before CodeDom I think).  I certainly wouldn't recommend using CodeDom to generate IL, I think that would be a very strange thing to do.